# Master table update returning output in 2 rows instead of 1

Tags: mysql

I have written a query to return tax differences for a particular tax between what was collected at the sale and what was billed. 
The Tax master table is updated whenever there is an update to the tax.
The query comprises of 3 union queries:

1. Tax calculated but not billed
2. Tax calculated and billed
3. Tax not calculated but is billed

In one of the cases, which falls under the second union the query is returning 2 records for one tax and the reason is that the tax was updated after it was billed. So, when the tax was billed it was processed under tax sequence 1 and later due to the tax update, the new tax sequence has become 2.
[TAX TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IGUX.png)

The 2 union query joint is a full outer join and as it finds 2 tax sequences it is returning 2 records which is incorrect.

I get 2 record lines, one with billed tax and another one for calculated whereas I expected only 1 record which can then calculate the difference between billed and calculated
[Incorrect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1sVm.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO5GO.png)

Comment: What is your question ? If it is `why I get 2 rows instead of 1` - you have already answered yourself (because of the outer join).

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I wanted to correct it and only get one record as the output.

Comment: If you need someone to correct the query for you - you should have had at least list the query in your question ... Otherwise I can only advice you to use inner join instead of the outer one.